# compound if statement and 'in' operator to check whether multiple substrings are contained in a string

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am checking whether two substrings are contained in another string:

```
if (substr1 and substr2) in str:
    my_func()
```

This does not work, the if statement is already being entered when only one substring is part of the string. Can someone explain why?

I found the following workaround, I'd simply like to know why Python behaves that way.

```
substr_list = [substr1, substr2]
if all(substr in str for substr in substr_list):
    my_func()
```

Comment: `(substr1 and substr2)` is a boolean.  Is the result of this expression in your string? No. Then you need to use separate expressions `if substr1 in str and substr2 in str:`

Comment: Intro: [shortcircuiting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not). The items in the parens are evaluated first and only one is taken. Bonus: Do not use `str` as a name. `str` is a builtin function which gets shadowed after an assignment to the name.

Comment: @Moses Koledoye: Thank you for introducing me to the term shortcircuiting

Comment: @DavidZemens: Thanks I felt like this was some specific behavior of the `in` operator

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because `(substr1 and substr2)` return `substr2` or operand which can convert to False and after this you verify `if substr2 in str`

```
'' and 'Some string'  # ''
'some value' and 'some value 2' # 'some value 2'
# full example
string_variable = 'some value' and 'some value 2' # You get 'some value 2'
string_variable in substr2
```

Comment: **False**: *return substr2 or False*. It returns one of the operands.  See [shortcircuiting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not)

Comment: You are right, not False but operand that give False. Edit answer

Answer (score -2):

So `and` works to check if two booleans (`True/False` values) are `True`, however `(substr1 and substr2)` is not a boolean. However, `substr1 in str` and `substr2 in str` and both booleans, so you can create a statement:

```
if substr1 in str and substr2 in str:
    myfunc()
```

Now in

```
substr_list = [substr1, substr2]
if all(substr in str for substr in substr_list):
    my_func()
```

The statement `(substr in str for substr in substr_list)` creates a generator that will return two boolean values. What `all` does is takes any iterable such a list of generator of booleans and returns a single boolean checking if they are all `True`.